# How to remove a specific index from a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to remove pieces of a multidimensional array if a certain condition is met.  The array can be as shown below, call it $friends:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[500]
          public 'id' => int 2
          public 'first_name' => string 'Mary' (length=4)
          public 'last_name' => string 'Sweet' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[501]
          public 'id' => int 9
          public 'first_name' => string 'Joe' (length=3)
          public 'last_name' => string 'Bob' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[502]
          public 'id' => int 1
          public 'first_name' => string 'Shag' (length=4)
          public 'last_name' => string 'Well' (length=4)
```

I have a function called is_followed, that let's me see if the id of one of the people in the array is being followed by the "user".  The code I am trying is:

```
//remove followed friends from the $friends array
$i=0;
foreach($friends as $friend) {
    foreach($friend as $f) {
        if(Fanfollow::is_followed($id,$f->id)) {
            unset($friend[$i]);
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

The $id is the id of the current user.

However, this is not working.  I know that using unset on `$friend` and not `$friends` is probably the issue.  But using unset on $friends also won't work, because it is the higher level array.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think the problem is with 'foreach'. I believe there was something about 'foreach working with a copy' or something. Try for($i; $i < count($friend); ++$i);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to take down the first parent keys, use the first foreach keys instead:

```
foreach($friends as $i => $friend) {
                //  ^ assign a key
    foreach($friend as $f) {
        if(Fanfollow::is_followed($id,$f->id)) {
            unset($friends[$i]);
            // unset this
        }
    }
}
```

Or if only for that single friend:

```
foreach($friends as $friend) {
    foreach($friend as $i => $f) {
                  //   ^ this key
        if(Fanfollow::is_followed($id,$f->id)) {
            unset($friend[$i]);
            // unset this
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) comes to the rescue:

```
array_filter($friend, 
  function($f) use($id) { return Fanfollow::is_followed($id,$f->id)); }
);
```

Though the solution with `foreach` is legit, `array_filter`is much more clear and sematically correct.